# Use tikz (for example) to draw pictures in hyperbolic geometry

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw pictures in the [Poincaré disk model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) for hyperbolic geometry.  Are there any built-in or add-on packages for tikz to do this?  For example, it would be nice to have functions for drawing [Saccheri quadrilaterals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccheri_quadrilateral) or [Lambert quadrilaterals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_quadrilateral) or asymptotic triangles.

(In my brief use so far, the [tkz-euclide](http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/euclide.html) package looks very good for Euclidean geometry, and now I'm looking for a hyperbolic analogue of it.)

Answer (score 13):

Here's another TikZ solution.  Given two points on the Poincare plane or disc, it draws the geodesic between them.  It does this by defining a (complicated!) `to` path which works out the circle and angles and then draws the correct arc.  It has some basic error checking to see if it ought to draw a straight line, but it checks for the *exact* condition rather than to within the precision of TeX so if your points are almost one above the other (or on the same radius) so that to all intents and purposes the geodesic is straight then this code might not detect that in time and end up dividing by something smaller than it should (as it is, I had to be careful how I broke up the calculations as some methods gave Big Numbers at partial stages).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19168/86}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter

\def\hyper@x#1,#2\relax{#1}
\def\hyper@y#1,#2\relax{#2}
\def\hyper@coords#1{#1}

\newif\ifhyper@vertical

\def\hyper@computer#1#2{%
  \edef\hyper@toscan{(#1)}
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hyper@coords\hyper@toscan
  \edef\hyper@sx{\the\pgf@x}
  \edef\hyper@sy{\the\pgf@y}
  \edef\hyper@toscan{(#2)}
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hyper@coords\hyper@toscan
  \edef\hyper@ex{\the\pgf@x}
  \edef\hyper@ey{\the\pgf@y}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@mx}{(\hyper@ex + \hyper@sx)/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@my}{(\hyper@ey + \hyper@sy)/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@dx}{\hyper@ex - \hyper@sx}
  \pgfmathparse{\hyper@dx == 0 ? "\noexpand\hyper@verticaltrue" : "\noexpand\hyper@verticalfalse"}
  \pgfmathresult
  \ifhyper@vertical
  \edef\hyper@cmd{-- (\tikztotarget)}
  \else
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@dy}{\hyper@ey - \hyper@sy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@t}{\hyper@my/\hyper@dx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@cx}{\hyper@mx + \hyper@t * \hyper@dy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@radius}{veclen(\hyper@cx - \hyper@sx, \hyper@sy)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@sangle}{180 - atan2(\hyper@sy,\hyper@cx-\hyper@sx)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@eangle}{180 - atan2(\hyper@ey,\hyper@cx-\hyper@ex)}
  \edef\hyper@cmd{arc[radius=\hyper@radius pt, start angle=\hyper@sangle, end angle=\hyper@eangle]}
  \fi
}

\def\hyper@disc@computer#1#2{%
  \edef\hyper@toscan{(#1)}
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hyper@coords\hyper@toscan
  \edef\hyper@sx{\the\pgf@x}
  \edef\hyper@sy{\the\pgf@y}
  \edef\hyper@toscan{(#2)}
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hyper@coords\hyper@toscan
  \edef\hyper@ex{\the\pgf@x}
  \edef\hyper@ey{\the\pgf@y}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@det}{\hyper@sx * \hyper@ey - \hyper@sy * \hyper@ex}
  \pgfmathparse{\hyper@det == 0 ? "\noexpand\hyper@verticaltrue" : "\noexpand\hyper@verticalfalse"}
  \pgfmathresult
  \ifhyper@vertical
  \edef\hyper@cmd{-- (\tikztotarget)}
  \else
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@mx}{(\hyper@ex + \hyper@sx)/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@my}{(\hyper@ey + \hyper@sy)/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@dx}{\hyper@ex - \hyper@sx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@dy}{\hyper@ey - \hyper@sy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@dradius}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hyperbolic disc radius}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@t}{((\hyper@dradius)^2 - \hyper@sx * \hyper@ex - \hyper@sy * \hyper@ey)/(2 * (\hyper@sx * \hyper@ey - \hyper@sy * \hyper@ex))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@radius}{sqrt((\hyper@t)^2 + .25) * veclen(\hyper@dx,\hyper@dy)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@cx}{\hyper@mx + \hyper@t * \hyper@dy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@cy}{\hyper@my - \hyper@t * \hyper@dx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@sangle}{atan2(\hyper@sy-\hyper@cy,\hyper@sx - \hyper@cx)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@eangle}{atan2(\hyper@ey-\hyper@cy,\hyper@ex - \hyper@cx)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@eangle}{\hyper@eangle > \hyper@sangle + 180 ? \hyper@eangle - 360 : \hyper@eangle}
  \edef\hyper@cmd{arc[radius=\hyper@radius pt, start angle=\hyper@sangle, end angle=\hyper@eangle]}
\fi
}

\def\hyper@plane@tangent#1#2{%
  \edef\hyper@toscan{(#1)}
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hyper@coords\hyper@toscan
  \edef\hyper@sx{\the\pgf@x}
  \edef\hyper@sy{\the\pgf@y}
  \edef\hyper@toscan{(#2)}
  \tikz@scan@one@point\hyper@coords\hyper@toscan
  \edef\hyper@ex{\the\pgf@x}
  \edef\hyper@ey{\the\pgf@y}
  % The difference between the end and start defines the tangent
  % vector
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@ex}{\hyper@ex - \hyper@sx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@ey}{\hyper@ey - \hyper@sy}
  % If we're straight up ...
  \pgfmathparse{\hyper@ex == 0 ? "\noexpand\hyper@verticaltrue" : "\noexpand\hyper@verticalfalse"}
  \pgfmathresult
  \ifhyper@vertical
  % Need to set length here, rescale to cm first
  % User \hyper@ey here as that remembers the sign
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@d}{\hyper@ey/1cm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@radius}{\hyper@sy * exp(\hyper@d) - \hyper@sy}
  \edef\hyper@cmd{-- ++(0,\hyper@radius pt)}
  \else
  % Set length
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@d}{\hyper@ex > 0 ? veclen(\hyper@ex,\hyper@ey) : -veclen(\hyper@ex,\hyper@ey)}
  % Radius of arc
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@radius}{abs(\hyper@sy * \hyper@d / \hyper@ex)}
  % Starting angle
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@sangle}{90 + atan(\hyper@ey/\hyper@ex)}
  % Ending angle, check if given
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/hyperbolic plane target angle}{\hyper@eangle}
  \ifx\hyper@eangle\pgfutil@empty
  % rescale into cm to avoid Big Numbers
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@d}{\hyper@d/1cm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@ey}{\hyper@ey/1cm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@tanhd}{tanh(\hyper@d)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\hyper@eangle}{acos((\hyper@d * \hyper@tanhd - \hyper@ey)/(\hyper@d - \hyper@ey * \hyper@tanhd))}
  %
  \fi
  \edef\hyper@cmd{arc[radius=\hyper@radius pt, start angle=\hyper@sangle, end angle=\hyper@eangle]}
\fi
}

\tikzset{%
  hyperbolic disc radius/.initial={1cm},
  hyperbolic plane/.style={
    to path={
      \pgfextra{\hyper@computer\tikztostart\tikztotarget}
      \hyper@cmd
    }
  },
  hyperbolic plane tangent/.style={
    to path={
      \pgfextra{\hyper@plane@tangent\tikztostart\tikztotarget}
      \hyper@cmd
    }
  },
  hyperbolic disc/.style={
    to path={
      \pgfextra{\hyper@disc@computer\tikztostart\tikztotarget}
      \hyper@cmd
    }
  },
  hyperbolic plane target angle/.initial={},
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every to/.style={hyperbolic plane}]
\fill[blue] (0,1) \foreach \k in {0,...,7} { to ++(\k * 45:2)};
\coordinate (b) at (1,2);
\coordinate (a) at (3,4);
\fill (a) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (b) circle[radius=2pt];
\draw (-2,0) -- (6,0);
\draw (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[hyperbolic disc radius=2cm,
every to/.style={hyperbolic disc}]
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hyperbolic disc radius}];
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hyperrad}{1/(2*sin(22.5))}
\fill[blue] (-112.5:\hyperrad) \foreach \k in {0,...,7} { to ++(\k * 45:1)};
\coordinate (b) at (1.2,.3);
\coordinate (a) at (.8,-.4);
\fill (a) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (b) circle[radius=2pt];
\draw (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every to/.style={hyperbolic plane tangent}]
\draw (1,2) circle[radius=2pt] to ++(1,1) circle[radius=4pt];
\draw[red] (-1,2) circle[radius=2pt] to[hyperbolic plane target angle=0]  ++(-60:2) circle[radius=4pt];
\draw (0,1) circle[radius=2pt] \foreach \k in {0,...,7} { to ++(\k * 45:1)};
\draw[thick,gray,<->] let \p{east}=(current bounding box.east), \p{west}=(current bounding box.west) in (\x{east},0) -- (\x{west},0);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: hyperbolic lines]

One extension that would be nice would be to be able to draw an arc from a point starting in a particular direction and going on for a particular length.  A hyperbolic version of the Euclidean `\draw (1,0) -- ++(45:2);`.

Comment: I've figured out how to do that last bit for the _plane_.  Now I've just the disc to do.  I haven't done actual computations in geometry for years!

Comment: This solution looks very elegent, but it seems like it isn't working anymore. I get this result instead: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/EQU3smZ) @LoopSpace Do you have an idea what could be broken?

Comment: @abenthy Try now.  Since the code was written, the `atan2` command in `pgfmath` had its arguments swapped (to fit in with the `atan2` command in every other programming language).  I've swapped it in the above and it works for me^TM.

Comment: works perfectly now, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Here is very basic solution. It get (some of) the job done. The use of `\hgline` should be obvious from the examples. Feel free to suggest improvements.

```
\documentclass[]{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\hgline}[2]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaone}{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetatwo}{#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{(\thetaone+\thetatwo)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phi}{abs(\thetaone-\thetatwo)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\close}{less(abs(\phi-90),0.0001)}
\ifdim \close pt = 1pt
    \draw[blue] (\theta+180:1) -- (\theta:1);
\else
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{tan(\phi)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\distance}{sqrt(1+\R^2)}
    \draw[blue] (\theta:\distance) circle (\R);
\fi
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\clip (0,0) circle (1);
\hgline{30}{-30}
\hgline{180}{270}
\hgline{30}{120}
\hgline{0}{180}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image: hyperbolic]

Comment: Great answer - I have added an improvement with my answer below (too much code for a comment), so that the when there is an angle >=180 between the two input angles, the geodesics still are drawn.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of using `tkz-euklide` to draw a hyperbolic line through two given points:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,0){A}
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
    \tkzDefPoint(0.3,-0.25){z1}
    \tkzDefPoint(-0.5,-0.5){z2}
    \tkzClipCircle(O,A)
    \tkzDefCircle[orthogonal through=z1 and z2](O,A)
    \tkzGetPoints{G}{g}
    \tkzDrawCircle(G,g)
    \tkzDrawPoints[color=black,fill=red,size=12](z1,z2)
    \tkzLabelPoints(z1,z2)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about the "orthogonal" argument to \tkzDrawCircle.  Is there actually a manual for tkz-euclide, or just a large collection of examples?  Anyway, this looks like a nice approach.

Comment: Never mind, I just found the manual (on CTAN, but not apparently on the original tkz-euclide web site).

Answer (score 3):

Improving on the answer of @Frederic to still draw the arcs when there is an angle >=180, even >360, between the two input angles. The only change is in the `\ifdim` loop, where an extra condition is added.

```
\newcommand{\hgline}[2]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaone}{mod(#1,360)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetatwo}{mod(#2,360)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{(\thetaone+\thetatwo)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phi}{abs(\thetaone-\thetatwo)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\close}{less(abs(\phi-90),0.0001)}
\ifdim \close pt = 1pt
    \draw[blue] (\thetaone:1) -- (\thetatwo:1);
\else
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{tan(\phi)}
    \ifdim \R pt < 0pt
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\distance}{sqrt(1+\R*\R)}
        \draw[blue] (\theta:-\distance) circle (\R);
    \else \ifdim \R pt > 0pt
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\distance}{sqrt(1+\R^2)}
        \draw[blue] (\theta:\distance) circle (\R);
        \fi
    \fi
\fi
}
```

First, if the angles are 180 degrees apart, the straight line drawn is directly in between them. Second, if the angles are more than 180 degrees apart, there is a catch that draws the correct circle. I also noticed that `\R^2` is negative if `\R` is negative, whereas `\R*\R` is not. For example, drawing the circle, clipping, and giving the command `\foreach \a in {120,130,...,300}{\hgline{\a}{30}}` gives the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.  I googled "latex hyperbolic geometry" and the top hit was this page.  There are plenty of papers about hyperbolic geometry written in latex but no packages that I found for hyperbolic geometry.

But I think these things can be done in TikZ, if one works hard enough.

Comment: I agree. Furthermore, drawing Saccheri and Lambert quadrilaterals seem quite simple in TikZ.

Comment: I agree that it's pretty easy to draw a Saccheri quadrilateral, for example, but I don't think it's a one-liner.  Marking the appropriate angles as right angles seems trickier.  In any case, I was hoping someone else had already done the hard work, so I wouldn't have to...

Comment: @John Palmieri: It may not be so hard since there are Euclidean constructions of the non-Euclidean lines.  Given points A and B in the Poincare disk, the center of the (Euclidean) circle which is the (hyperbolic) line between them has center at the intersection of the perpendicular bisector to the (Euclidean) line segment AB and the boundary circle.  So you can code it up in `tkz-euclide`.

Comment: @Matthew:  Are you sure about that?  Geodesics should be orthogonal to the boundary circle, and the way I read your description, I don't see why those circles should be orthogonal.

Comment: @Jan: Well I was at the time I wrote it.  I thought that the center of the geodesic circle had to be on the boundary circle.  If that were true then there's only two places to put it: where the circle intersects the perpendicular bisector.  But looking at it now with a few more cases makes me think that's not correct.  *Sigh.*  I was a symplectic geometer, not a hyperbolic geometer.  Is this construction valid on the upper-half plane model for hyperbolic geometry?

Comment: @Jan and all: To redeem myself, [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/99/hyp_disk) is a construction of the hyperbolic line through two points in the Poincaré disk.  You can find the third point defining the geodesic circle by inverting one of the points in the boundary circle.

Comment: @Matthew:  It is true in the upper half plane model.  The problem is that while the Moebius transformation that takes the upper half plane to the circle maps circles and lines to circles and lines, it does not map centers to centers.

Comment: @Matthew: You are right that you can use `tkz-euklide`, though.  In fact, there is an example like that in the `tkz-euklide` manual, the example 9.7.2.

Comment: @Jan: quite right, I figured it out about the centers.  But I think the real tikz-y way would be as a path-morphing decoration.  The coordinates of the geodesic circle's center are rational functions of the coordinates of the points, right?

Answer (score 2):

kind of what you are looking for, i hope it helps. its not in euclidean though

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
....
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black,thick] (0,1.5) -- (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,1.5); %the rectangle part
\draw [black, thick] plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates {(0,1.5)(1.5,1)(3,1.5)};%smooth curve top that follows these lines
\end{tikzpicture}
```

this is what it looks like
[image]