# Creating a Tessellated Hyperbolic Disk with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking to create this using Tikz:

[image: Disk]

I've thought of trying to use conformal mappings although I highly doubt that's the correct way of doing it. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Source of the image: [https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/lectures/FWCG10.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ebishop/lectures/FWCG10.pdf)

Comment: Have you looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16617/86 ? There's a few different approaches to drawing hyperbolic diagrams there.

Comment: for a reference, you can see and modify this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452022/140722

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A small example with tikz. It should be possible to simplify more, but I do not know the guideline to place the smaller circles (centers, radii, angles, etc.).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (4);  
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) circle (4);
    \foreach\i in {0,72,...,360}
    {
      \draw (\i:5)       circle (4);
      \draw (\i+12:5)    circle (2);
      \draw (\i-12:4.5)  circle (1.5);
      \draw (\i+36:4.25) circle (1);
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** Another code, following Andrew Stacey suggestion. Now the circles meet each one perpendicularly, I think.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\R{4}
\newcommand{\mycircle}[2] % radius, angle
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\d{sqrt(\R*\R+#1*#1)};
  \draw(#2:\d) circle (#1);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (\R);  
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) circle (\R);
    \foreach\i in {0,72,...,360}
    {
      \mycircle{5}{\i}
      \mycircle{1.55}{\i+12};
      \mycircle{1.55}{\i-12};
      \mycircle{0.8}{\i+36};
      \mycircle{0.8}{\i-36};
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, in a hyperbolic diagram then the inner circles are meant to meet the outer one perpendicularly.  So the centres aren't located on the outer circle but at the intersection of certain tangents to the outer circle.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, Thank you!!! I guess I should know that... :(

Answer (score 3):

A template in PSTricks only for emergency, fun, and comparison purposes.
You just need to figure out how to specify mathematically the location of the smaller circles on the big one (or probably not on it).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psclip{\pscircle{5}}
        \foreach \a in {0,30,...,330}{\pscircle(5;\a){2}}
    \endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, in a hyperbolic diagram then the inner circles are meant to meet the outer one perpendicularly.  So the centres aren't located on the outer circle but at the intersection of certain tangents to the outer circle.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Thank you for informing it. :-)