# Drawing Triangles and Quadrilaterals in Hyperbolic Geometry Using the Poincaré Disk Model: Error with tkz-euclide Package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw triangles/quadrilaterals in hyperbolic geometry, specifically in the Poincaré disk model. I found a code that seems simple to use but it's causing an error.

[The code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16749/263209) I found is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,0){A}
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDefPoint(0.3,-0.25){z1}
  \tkzDefPoint(-0.5,-0.5){z2}
  \tkzClipCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z1 and z2](O,A)
  \tkzDrawPoints[color=black,fill=red,size=12](z1,z2)
  \tkzLabelPoints(z1,z2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, when I try to compile this code on *Overleaf*, I get the following error:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/orthogonal through', to which you passed 'z1 and z2', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

I have checked the [manual](https://altermundus.fr/files/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide.pdf) for `tkz-euclide` but I can't seem to find the particular use of argument `orthogonal through...` paired with the `\tkzDrawCircle` function.

Can someone help me fix this code?

Comment: It seems that `orthogonal through` only exists for `\tkzDefCircle`. So, you could do something like `\tkzDefCircle[orthogonal through=z1 and z2](O,A) \tkzGetPoints{G}{g} \tkzDrawCircle(G,g)`. I am unsure why the linked answer worked.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you so much for your prompt response! Your solution works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check whether the linked answer has worked at some point in time, but with a recent version of `tkz-euclide`, `orthogonal trough` obviously doesn't work with `\tkzDrawCircle`, but it works with `\tkzDefCircle`.

You can draw the circle via adding `\tkzGetPoints{G}{g} \tkzDrawCircle(G,g)` to the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,0){A}
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDefPoint(0.3,-0.25){z1}
  \tkzDefPoint(-0.5,-0.5){z2}
  \tkzClipCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDefCircle[orthogonal through=z1 and z2](O,A)
  \tkzGetPoints{G}{g}
  \tkzDrawCircle(G,g)
  \tkzDrawPoints[color=black, fill=red, size=5](z1,z2)
  \tkzLabelPoints(z1,z2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]